# Proof: $\exists{\xi}\in(a,b) \text{s.t. } \frac{1}{2}f''(\xi)=\frac{f(a)}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{f(b)}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{f(c)}{(c-a)(c-b)}$

Tags: real-analysis

> $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f''(x)$ exists on $(a,b)$. 
>   $\\Proof:$
>   $\forall{c}\in(a,b)\text{, } \exists{\xi} \in(a,b) \text{ such
>  that}\\$$$\frac{1}{2}f''(\xi)=\frac{f(a)}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{f(b)}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{f(c)}{(c-a)(c-b)}$$

It seems that I should changed the formula into $\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$, where
$$F(x)=f(a)(x-b)+f(b)(a-x)+f(x)(b-a)\\G(x)=\frac{1}{2}(a-b)(b-x)(x-a)$$
and since $\frac{F''(x)}{G''(x)}=f''(x)$, by using Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem, I could find a way though $$\\\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\frac{F(x)-F(a)}{G(x)-G(a)}=\frac{F'(\xi')}{G'(\xi')}=\frac{F'(\xi')-F'(a)}{G'(\xi')-G'(a)}=\frac{F''(\xi)}{G''(\xi)}=f''(\xi)$$
But while $F(a)$ and $G(a)$ do equals $0$, $\text{ }\\F'(x)=f(a)-f(b)+f'(x)(b-a)\text{  equals 0 at somewhere between $a$ and $b$}\\\text{and }G(x)=\frac{a+b}{2}-x\text{ equals 0 at the middle point of $a$ and $b$}.$

I have no idea where to go.
Would you help me with this question? Best ragards.

Comment: I'm confused how $f''$ even exists.

Comment: It would help to state clearly what formula are you trying to prove...

Comment: @lan I'm sorry. The first line should be $f''(x)$ exists on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Momo I edited the question. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$F(x) = f(x)-\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)} f(a) - \frac{(x-a)(x-c)}{(b-a)(b-c)} f(b) - \frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)} f(c) $$

Then $F(a)=F(b)=F(c)=0$, successive applications of Rolle's theorem gives an $\xi\in(a,b)$ and $F''(\xi)= 0$.

This $\xi$ satisfies $$\frac{1}{2}f''(\xi)=\frac{f(a)}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{f(b)}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{f(c)}{(c-a)(c-b)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I have not even think about Rolle's theorem. :-D